# recogniser.listen(source) doesn't stop listening

Tags: python, speech-recognition, voice, pyttsx

I am making a python script which listens to your voice then executes functions based on what you've said.

I have just started making a 'wake-up word' and the code looks like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source1:
            SpeakText("one")
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source1)
            print("Set minimum energy threshold to {}".format(r.energy_threshold))
            SpeakText("two")
            audio1 = r.listen(source)
            SpeakText("three")
            MyText = r.recognize_google(audio1)
            print(MyText)
            SpeakText("four")
            MyText = MyText.lower()

            if MyText == "oink" or "ink" or "link":
                playsound("oink_boop.mp3")
                detect_command()
                        
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("No Speech or No Internet")
```

Now I put in the SpeakText parts (using pyttsx3) just for debugging purposes but it says 'two' then gets stuck listening to my speech on the audio1 = r.listen(source)

It doesn't seem to stop listening to me, I even tried muting my microphone but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-en')
        your_query_Fuction(query)
    except Exception:
        print("No Speech or No Internet")
        your_Mic_Fuction()
```

You should also use:
 `if 'oink' in MyText or ...`

Edit:
Use this one.

```
def your_Mic_Fuction():
    while True:
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            r.pause_threshold = 1
            audio = r.listen(source)

        try:
            query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-en')
            your_query_Fuction(query)
        except Exception:
            print("No Speech or No Internet")
            your_Mic_Fuction()

def your_query_Fuction(query):
    if "oink" in query or "ink" in query or "link" in query:
        playsound("oink_boop.mp3")

your_Mic_Fuction()
```

Comment: Should I keep the r.adjust_for_ambient_noise?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this:

```
    with sr.Microphone() as source1:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source1)
        r.pause_threshold = 1
            
        audio1 = r.listen(source1)
    try:
        
            MyText = r.recognize_google(audio1, language='en-en')
            MyText = MyText.lower()
            if "oink" in MyText or "ink" in MyText or "link" in MyText:
                playsound("oink_boop.mp3")
                detect_command()
                        
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("No Speech or No Internet")
```

It still doesn't work
Have I done anything wrong?